# Signalr client to server push using abstract model

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, signalr, signalr-hub

I've managed to set up communication using Signalr from both sides. When sending a message from server to client, I use an abstract model and have only one method at client.

I wanted to know if there was a possible way to do so similiary from the other side - from client to server, because so far I can't get this to work.

My meaning is:

Server side:

```
public class MyHub : Hub
{
     public void HandleNotification(BaseNotification notification)
     {
         if(notification is NewItemNotification) {
                ....
         } else if (notification is UpdatedItemNotification) {
                ....
         } else if (notification is DeletedItemNotification) {
                ....
         }
     }
}
```

In the following example I get an empty `BaseNotification` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to how Json.Net library (internally used by SignalR) works.

When data gets to the server in Json format, SignalR will take that string and convert it to `BaseNotification` object. All properties defined in the Json that don´t exists in `BaseNotification` type will be dismissed. In other words: properties not present in `BaseNotification` won´t be deserialized. So your `BaseNotification` cannot be casted to a different type unless the property names in both types are equal.

I can think of two different solutions for your case:

a) Include all notification properties in a single object `Notification`, adding one more for the type (i.e: Enum `NotificationType`):

```
public void HandleNotification(Notification notification)
{
    switch (notification.Type)
    {
        case NotificationType.NewItem:
            ...
        case NotificationType.UpdatedItem:
            ...        
        case NotificationType.DeletedItem:
            ...
}
```

b) Create a different handle method for each notification type:

```
public void HandleNewNotification(NewItemNotification notification) {}
public void HandleUpdatedNotification(UpdatedItemNotification notification) {}
public void HandleDeletedNotification(DeletedItemNotification notification) {}
```